# Deleting registry keys in batch file (ERROR: Access is denied)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I'm trying to delete registry keys in a batch file, here's what I'm doing.

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM" /f
```

I'm recieving the following error:

```
ERROR: Access is denied.
```

Yet I can simply open regedit.exe and right click and delete the registry key no problem! To state the obvious, I have elevated the batch file instance as administrator, am logged in as administrator, and tried running the batch from a cmd and powershell instance both as administrator. The Administrator account has full permissions for the registry keys, which is why I'm able to delete them simply through the regedit GUI. This is part of a large batch file script, the point is I want the whole process to be automated. Any ideas?

Comment: Not answering the actual question, but if your goal is to remove sccm instances from cliens, take a look at ccmclean.exe. Ref.: https://www.anoopcnair.com/configmgr-sccm-2012-uninstallremove-cm-2012-client-using-ccmclean-exe/. It worked like a charm in our enviroment.

Comment: "When in doubt: run procmon". Try executing your batch file with `procmon` running, find the error and look at its details *(or post them here)*. Among others, it shows you the session its running in, the actual user being used, ...

Comment: Can you lauch that `reg delete` from a normal commandline or an administrator one?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of companies have a GPO setting called 'Prevent Access To Registry Editing Tools' set to 'Yes'.
Maybe that is the culprit here. When you run regedit yourself, the machine wil probably show you a UAC message first and next you click 'OK' on that?

You may get a useful errormessage if you try to delete the key using a different scripting language like VBScript:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim objReg, strKeyPath, strComputer

strComputer = "."

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
                       strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM"
objReg.DeleteKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath
Set objReg = Nothing
```

or using PowerShell:

```
Remove-Item -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM' -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a follow up to @Theo response, it seems like somethings preventing you access as that command *should* work. I would suggest trying his idea then if it does not work, trying this one.

Since you have admin access you could attempt to give `Everyone` perms to the key as all you want to do is simply remove it. The `REGINI` command can do this but will add some bulk to the script.

```
::Grant perms to REG key
echo \Registry\machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NEW [7] >> "%~dp0KeyPermx.txt"
REGINI %~dp0KeyPermx.txt
del %~dp0KeyPermx.txt

::Remove the key
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NEW" /f
```